# Is it possible to set who's the site owner when a new site is created programmatically? (SharePoint)

Tags: sharepoint

I am creating sites programmatically in a web part and I wonder if it's possible to set who the site owner is? By default the one who creates the site is the owner but I am going to use this web part for a customer and I don't want to be the owner of the sites. Do I have to change this afterwards or is it possible to set when the site is created?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The SPSite constructor takes the owner parameters right, can you just change that to who you want it to be?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spsitecollection.add.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a site collection, use djeeg's suggestion. If you are creating a subsite, permissions will be inherited from the parent site by default unless you call [BreakRoleInheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.breakroleinheritance.aspx). If that is the case, you can create a new group, assign it to the [AssociatedOwnerGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.associatedownergroup.aspx) property, and then add the appropriate users to that group.